# Disable 'phpdoc_var_without_name' option phpcsfixer

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

How can I disable this option from phpcsfixer?
I want to use :

```
   /**
    * @var ObjectType $object
    */
```

But not,

```
/**@var ObjectType $type*/
```

But phpcsfixer will remove the variable name in the first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add

```php
'phpdoc_var_without_name' => false
```

to your config.